# Control music playlist from website with Raspberry Pi push buttons

Tags: raspberry-pi

I'm programming a website where you can choose mp3's to play from a playlist. The webiste must be accessed from a Raspberry Pi. The Raspberry has 3 buttons(next, previous, pause). Can I control the playlist with the buttons? So when I press next, the next song on the website will start.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the website to change the song or is the website an interface to the raspberry pi, which playes the files?

Comment: The website must change the song when I push the button on the Raspberry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably could make a file containing a variable. every few seconds the website loads that file via java script and checks the value. When you press a key on the RPi, you could change that value, the website will read it (and reset it) and change the song. I would generate this file via PHP, as this can be run on the server and on command line.

Comment: Thanks! That seems possible. could you help me to the right direction please? Sorry but I have not many experience with this.

Answer (score 0):

you can attach a listener on the keypress of a keyboard touch and make a I/O for the raspberry, could it be okay for you?